# Store JSON file in Cordova app

Tags: cordova

I have a JSON file that contains some application data (points on a map) that I would like to store on the application when it goes to the iOS App Store. Is it as simple as placing the JSON file in the www directory and then using the Cordova File API to access it? Is there a specific place in the Cordova app that I need to put the JSON file to ensure it can be accessed?

Thanks

Comment: why not store on your server and request data when needed?

Comment: @MarcinMikolajczyk That's an option but it's not necessary to download that data if it can be stored on the device from the start, it doesn't need updating so it should just be on the device from the go

Comment: having such data static in app is just wrong approach. you can store files as any other resources like html/js/css files

Comment: you can store json file anywhere in your www folder and get it using ajax call by giving url of local file. no need to use file api.

Comment: @MarcinMikolajczyk I'm sorry but that is completely untrue. Many applications have to store data on the device locally. Just because Cordova runs as a hybrid app doesn't mean everything has to be fetched from the web via the application. Apps store data locally on the device to ensure fast content delivery

Comment: @Jskidd3 I agree that some data can be stored locally, but here we are talking about positions of pins on map. having this staticly closes opportunity to update the pins in future without reinstalling app, thats completely wrong imo. Map also has to be "downloaded" first, so downloading pins wouldnt hurt much.

Comment: @MarcinMikolajczyk Our app has a system to update the JSON file already, it's just that we wanted to store the JSON file initially on the device and weren't sure how to go about it. I see where you're coming from about the map but our application is storing tens of thousands of markers that are only to be displayed when a certain zoom level is achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store json file anywhere in your www folder and get it using ajax call by giving url of local file. no need to use file api.